# What's the practical difference in an image taken at focal length of 200mm vs 300mm?

Tags: lens, zoom, focal-length, field-of-view

I'm confused about the 200mm and the 300mm zoom ranges. I am looking for some examples of the same subject, in order to visualize the difference between 200mm and 300mm focal lengths.

I want to compare the results for a very distant subject (like the moon) to a far subject (may be 1km away) and a nearer subject (around 100 meter away).

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is. Asking for sample images is maybe better done in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

Basically the 300mm gets you closer to your subject. The magnification is greater than with a 200mm focal length!

Hope that helps somehow!

Comment: This answer would be significantly better if you described the simple math in going from one to the other. That is: zooming is just like cropping, and going from 200 to 300 is like taking the center ²⁰⁰⁄₃₀₀ths — or ²⁄₃rds! — of the image. Teach a person to fish, and all that....

Comment: Why do I have to add this? :) The person asked the question wanted to see samples.

Comment: But in case he wants to know, there is optical zoom 1.5x (300/200), if that helps :)

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but, we want answers that explain. That's more useful in the long run, _and_ more actually useful to the person who asked the question. Often when I talk to new photographers with this particular question, they imagine that there is a complicated formula, or maybe even something particular to each lens and no formula at all. So, I know from experience that the further explanation here is really valuable. I can add it as a separate competing answer, but I figured you could probably cover it. :)

Comment: Thank you for noticing! Are you talking about the optical zoom? I have already referred to it.